# Pushing information onto a TabBar instead of a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am able to download a file and see the progress on the ViewController when I push it through a NavigationController. However I want to show the downloads on another tabBar since my model is based on that.

The Problem: When I select to see the TabBar in question I get nothing.

I have tried: `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;` But that obviously only shows the ViewController and does not push the info onto it.

Any know how I need to change the bottom code to get the result I want?

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[request setUserInfo:dictionary];
[downloadTableViewObj setDownloadDirectory:path];
[downloadTableViewObj addDownloadRequest:request];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:downloadTableViewObj animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your Architecture but `UITabBarController` have method like :

> viewControllers
>   An array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface.
>   @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers

You can access the right view controller at the index you want to send it message, before or after having the tabBar change it's selection.

Also note that `UITabBarController` can have a `delegate` that implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. That can be useful in some circumstances, but I don't think yours is a good candidate for it.

---

```
NSArray *ar = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;  
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)ar[3];   
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
[nav pushViewController:downloadTableViewObj animated:YES];
```

I haven't try that particular code but something with that kind of logic should work.

Comment: I have it set up through storyboard - so I may be missing the code base to do that, since SB takes care of that.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg if you can do `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;` you can look at it like this : `NSArray *ar = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;`

Comment: The itunes app has what I want - so I am trying to replicate that

Comment: Cool what ius the "that" you are using?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg sorry, I was just to lazy to copy past from your question